# Условие в цикле foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Здравствуйте! Не знаю как правильно вывести сообщение об ошибке.
Есть массив, который я получаю из базы.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [login] => test [pass] => 4eb264b92fce195a0b145a1ead789db14b6ae997 [email] => test@test.com ) )
```

Попытался написать так:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
        if ($value['login'] == $login) {
            echo "This login is exist<br>";
            unset($login);
        }

        if ($value['email'] == $email) {
            echo "This email is exist<br>";
            unset($email);
        }
    }
```

Но не получается проверить второй if. Постоянно работает не так как надо.
Далее у меня идет запрос в базу и если эти переменные есть то он отправляет данные, если их нет то все на этом заканчивается. Но если у меня первое условие возвращяет TRUE то второе не проверяется и сообщение не выводится. А если первое условие возвращает FALSE и даже если второе должно вернуть TRUE данные все равно заносятся вместо того чтобы вывести сообщение об ошибке. Вобщем я что-то непонимаю как этот foreach работает.

Как написать нормальную проверку двух переменных для ассоциативного массива?

```
//соединение с базой и добавление данных
if(isset($login,$email,$pass)) {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test")
    or die('Failed to connect to MySQL Server');
$query = "INSERT INTO persons (login, pass, email) VALUES ('$login', '$pass', '$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)
        or die('Failed to connect to MySQL Server.');
mysqli_close($con);

    if(isset($login,$email,$pass)) {
        echo "$login<br>";
        echo "$email<br>";
        echo "$pass<br>";
        echo '<h1>Your information has been successfully added to the database!<h1>';
    }
}
```

Comment: > Далее у меня идет запрос в базу и если эти переменные есть то он отправляет данные

покажи что дальше происходит, я подозреваю что не в foreach проблема

Comment: в данной реализации, я как минимум добавил бы:

    if (isset($login) && $value['login'] == $login) {

и для почты то-же самое...

А не легче было запрос сделать так, чтобы давал записи с совпадением логина, почты?